# Is the deployment descriptor obsolete in Java EE?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, annotations

I have seen java web applications written without the deployment descriptor(web.xml) after the introduction of special annotations.

Has annotations completely replaced the deployment descriptor in java EE? 
is using DD considered as obsolete? 
Can any java EE application be written without the deployment descriptor in new java versions?

Comment: Does it mean that, a combination of xml configuration and annotations is used?

Comment: Annotation is metadata. If you are using annotation then there will be no need of web.xml

Comment: so no combination can be used? if we are using web.xml can't we also use annotations?

Comment: Yes, you can but the descriptor will supersede the annotation in case of conflicts

Comment: You're not going to escape the web.xml in many cases and scenarios. For example, ordering of filters is still not supported in annotations. Deploying JAX-WS services in a servlet container is still heavily xml-config dependent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web servers may have their own default deployment descriptor files, like default-web.xml in Glassfish server for web applications (web.xml in web app just overrides it). Here is full info about [GlassFish Server Deployment Descriptor Files](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2417/giida.html).

Comment: In a lot of cases, theres no need for glassfish descriptors too. Anyway, descriptors are not obsolete, although annotations are preferable for they enable declarative style.